# Answer to this Haskell expression

Tags: haskell, expression, list-comprehension

The following expression `[y | x <- [1..3], y <- [x..x*2]]` produces the answer `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Can someone please explain the steps involved in reaching this answer?

Comment: That's a list comprehension. Do you understand them in general? [Here](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like a foreach loop, so

```
foreach (x in [1..3]) {
  foreach (y in [x .. x * 2]) {
    yield y;
  }
}
```

First x is 1, so y in [1 .. 2]

Then  x is 2, so y in [2 .. 4]

Then  x is 3, so y in [3 .. 6]

Concatenate these results together and you get the final result.